# slncrypto lib for lua

Tags: windows, encryption, lua

Has anyone gotten "slncrypto" for lua to work?

Always the "crypto" module seems to be missing and I can't find it in any downloads nor are there any dlls included.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a .dll or .so named `crypto` from `slncrypt.c` because this C file exports `luaopen_crypto`. Then you do `require"crypto"`. The test program in http://files.luaforge.net/releases/sln/slncrypto/1.1 works fine for me when I do all this.

Comment: Can you tell me how to create the dll? Exactly what I need to type. I have mingw, cywin or visual express at my disposal. I tried it several times before but it didn't work.

Comment: @user1058431, I'm sorry, I don't have access to a Windows box.